# Can I share gui code between chrome extension and desktop based application?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cross-browser, desktop-application, selenium-ide

I have to write a desktop based RPA recorder (and playback) to record actions in desktop based applications. I also want to record actions in websites/web based applications. The later can be deployed as chrome extension or again standalone desktop based application. For later, I have found selenium ide/sideed/katalon recorder.

Since the GUI that I want to support is different from these apps (these GUIs have written in React and are deployed as chrome extension), my question is that is there a way to write GUI code once and reusable across desktop based RPA recorder and web based RPA recorder, like can I write it in java or something? (Does chrome extension support java code?.). On similar line, can I convert chrome extension app to desktop based app?.

Comment: Extensions are JavaScript/HTML/CSS.

Comment: @wOxxOm can i write a java based standalone program and call chrome extension code so that i can write gui in java and use web recorder from extension..any thoughts?.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write a chrome extension and a desktop app using the same codebase, one way to accomplish this would be to create the chrome extension (html, css and JavaScript) and then use [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/es/) for the desktop app, electron which is the same framework where some popular tools are built such a vs code, is a tool that will let you use web technologies, so you could re use the entire codebase of the chrome extension and for some elements that won’t exist in electron like the chrome APIs you could write your own wrappers so they work seamlessly